# Generalisation of Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

So, the theorem states that if f is holomorphic in $U = B(0,1)$ (so, $\{z \in C : |z| < 1\}$) and if it holds that $|f(z)| \leq R + |a|$ for all $z \in U$ and $f(0) = 0$,
then it holds that:

1)$|f(z)| \leq |z|$

2)$|f'(0)| \leq 1$

Furthermore, if equality holds either in 1) or in 2) we have that f is a rotation for some angle $\rho$.

Now, why shouldn't hold the following:

If f is holomorphic in $U = B(a,R)$ for $a \in C$ and for $R > 0$ and it holds that $|f(z)| \leq R$ for all $z \in U$ and $f(a) = 0$(maybe here $f(a) = a$). Then it holds that:

1)$|f(z)| \leq |z|$

2)$|f'(0)| \leq R$??

Comment: Sorry, your statement of the Schwarz Lemma is somewhat strange. Shouldn't it be "if $f:U\to U$ is holomorphic and $f(0)=0$, then $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for every $z\in U$ and $|f'(0)|\leq 1$"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a statement for $B(a,R)$, just consider the biholomorphism $\sigma:B(0,1)\to B(a,R)$ given by $\sigma(z)=a+Rz$. Now, it depends on the hypotheses you want to use

1) Then if $f:B(a,R)\to B(a,R)$ and $f(a)=a$, you have $\sigma^{-1}\circ f\circ \sigma=g$ and $g:B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ with $g(0)=0$, so $|g(z)|<|z|$, i.e.
$$|\sigma^{-1}(f(\sigma(z))|\leq|z|$$
i.e. putting $w=\sigma(z)$
$$|f(w)-a|/R\leq|w-a|/R$$
i.e.
$$|f(w)-a|\leq|w-a|\;.$$

In the same way, you get
$$|g'(0)|\leq 1$$
i.e.
$$|(\sigma^{-1})'(a)f'(a)\sigma'(0)|\leq 1$$
that is
$$|\frac{1}{R}f'(a)R|\leq 1$$
i.e.
$$|f'(a)|\leq 1\;.$$

2) If you consider instead $f:B(a,R)\to B(0,1)$, you will define $g=f\circ\sigma$ and do the same kind of computation, obtaining
$$R|f(w)|\leq |w-a|$$
$$R|f'(a)|\leq 1$$

3) If you want $f:B(a,R)\to B(0,R)$, you consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{R}f(Rz+a)$ and obtain
$$|f(w)|\leq |w-a|$$
$$|f'(a)|\leq 1$$